# Selecting unique tuple based on two combined columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
|------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|
|    id      |  social_media |   post_userid  |    value      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1      |    facebook   |    1000012     |     12        |
|------------|---------------|----------------|---------------|
|     2      |    facebook   |    1000012     |     14        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     3      |    twitter    |    10023       |     12        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     4      |    facebook   |    1000014     |     12        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     5      |  google plus  |      123       |     14        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

In the table I have `2 facebook users having id 1000012 and 1000014`
`one twitter user having id 10023`, and `one googleplus user having id 123`.

So the `social_media` and `post_userid` combined identifies a unique user.

So how can I get a distinct user based on a combination of `social_media` and `post_userid`?

Comment: Is this a trick question? SELECT DISTINCT social_media, post_userid FROM a table; !?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT social_media, post_userid FROM my_table
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
 Select id ,social_media ,   post_userid  ,    value
 From table t1
 Where id = (Select Max(id) from table t2
               where t1.post_userid = t.post_userid)
```